# Filter on column and also sort in descending order in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I sort in descending order but also filter on column in AngularJS? I have the following code that will default to the most recent timestamp.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in log | orderBy:'-timestamp' ">
    <td>{{item.timestamp | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM'}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Action | removeHTMLTags | strip }}</td>
    <td>{{item.AO}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I also have the following js code that will work for filtering on the column header.

```
            $scope.reverseOrder = true;
            $scope.sortField = '';
            $scope.sortBy = function(sortField) {
                $scope.reverseOrder = ($scope.sortField == sortField) ? !$scope.reverseOrder : false;
                $scope.sortField = sortField;
            }


      <tr ng-repeat="item in log | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder">
        <td>{{item.timestamp | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM'}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Action | removeHTMLTags | strip }}</td>
        <td>{{item.AO}}</td>
      </tr>
```

I would like to both filter on the column but also default to show the most recent timestamps on top.

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
ng-repeat="item in log | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder | orderBy: '-timestamp'"
```

Comment: Do you want to dynamically specify the column you want to search from? also are your timestamps unix timestamps or mysql type formatted timestamp strings

Comment: I want to be able to do the same as what  is working here https://codepen.io/centem/pen/BaajLZm 
Clicking on the table header changes the orderBy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand why your code isn't working you must understand first, how the orderBy filter works in angularjs. In your ng-repeat the orderBy filter has two parameters sortField and reverseOrder. For them to work you must have a controller that has two $scope variables named respectively sortField and reverseOrder. The first parameter is to determine which key should orderBy use to order your array and the second one is a boolean that specifies would the order be reversed or not.

In my attempt to reproduce your example, I took the liberty of using unix timestamps in my logs array. So in the controller,

```
$scope.searchText = "";
$scope.sortField = "timestamp";
$scope.reverseOrder = false;
$scope.logs = [
  {
    timestamp : 2147450400000,
    Action : 'bal sal',
    AO : 'abcd'
  },
  {
    timestamp : 979840800000,
    Action : 'bal sal2',
    AO : 'abcd2'
  },
  {
    timestamp : 1579370400000,
    Action : 'bal sal2',
    AO : 'abcd2'
  }      
]

$scope.sortBy = function(sortField) {
  $scope.reverseOrder = ($scope.sortField === sortField) ? !$scope.reverseOrder : false;
  $scope.sortField = sortField;
};
```

Also in the example you provided, they passed the column name via a function. So in your html you need to have something like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
<table>
  <thead>
    <th ng-click="sortBy('timestamp')">Time Stamp</th>
    <th ng-click="sortBy('Action')">Action</th>
    <th ng-click="sortBy('AO')">AO</th>
  </thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in logs | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder| filter:searchText">
      <td>{{item.timestamp | date :'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM'}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Action}}</td>
      <td>{{item.AO}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this clears your confusions.

Comment: How do you get it to show the most recent dates as the initial sorting. I've tried reversing the booleans but it only shows the most recent dates upon triggering the ng-clicks.

Comment: notice in the controller, I have $scope.sortField = "timestamp"; and $scope.reverseOrder = false; this defines that the before anything is pressed your logs will be ordered by 'timestamp' key and your reversed flag will be false